# display menus on all page except one?

Tags: menus, sidebar

I'm not very good at this, so please bear with me. I have a Wordpress site with sections for different cites, and the different cities each have their own nav menu which shows for all of the pages in that city.

```
if ( is_page( 'phnom-penh' ) || in_array( '11760', $ancestors ) ) :
    get_sidebar( 'city-phnom-penh' );
```

However, I want to remove the menu/sidebar just from one page in the Phnom Penh section so I can add a widgetized sidebar to that page instead. Is it possible to have this sidebar apply to all pages in that section *except* for one?

Comment: Yes - it's possible - does your code not work, if not, what errors do you get? - perhaps try ```! is_page( 'phnom-penh' )```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. The code above puts the sidebar on *all* pages within the phnom-penh section, but I want to specifically exclude one page within that secion. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

As I noted in my comment, you can use the negation operator, like so:

```php
if ( ! is_page( 'phnom-penh' ) ) {
    get_sidebar( 'not-phnom-penh' );
} else {
    get_sidebar( 'phnom-penh' );
}
```

Note the `!` before the `is_page` - that means NOT.

Also note that if you use more than once condition via `||` or `OR` and either of the conditions returns true - the sidebar will be returned.

Comment: So that means if the page is NOT phnom-penh it will get the all-other-cities sidebar? The issue is the specific page I want the alternate sidebar is nested under phnom-penh.

Could I do something like this?  
  
`if ( is_page( 'phnom-penh' ) || in_array( '11760', $ancestors ) ) :  get_sidebar( 'city-phnom-penh' );  
    
if ( is_page( '83571' )  
 get_sidebar( 'sidebar' );`

Comment: Updated with an example..